# How to create trigger on delete from table to drop corresponding view?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to create trigger that drops the view when the row that contains name of that view is deleted from table.

Consider following table, view.

```
CREATE TABLE views
(
  id serial NOT NULL, 
  name character varying(128) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT views_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT views_name_unique UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test AS 
SELECT * FROM views;

INSERT INTO views (name) VALUES('test');
```

I create trigger to drop view on delete from table `views`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_view()

RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

viewname varchar(128);

BEGIN
    viewname := OLD.name;
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS viewname;
    RETURN NULL;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION drop_spatial_view()
  OWNER TO postgres;


CREATE TRIGGER del
  AFTER DELETE
  ON views
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE drop_view();
```

When I delete row from `views` I get an error:

```
DELETE FROM views WHERE name = 'test';

NOTICE:  view "viewname" does not exist, skipping
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DROP VIEW IF EXISTS viewname"
```

Seems that there is an issue with assignment of value `test` to variable `viewname`. How to rewrite trigger to make it work?

Comment: @lad2025, it works this way, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `DDL` syntax inside routines you need to use Dynamic-SQL.

Change:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS viewname;
```

to:

```
EXECUTE 'DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ' || viewname;
```